# Computing distance between between 2 point of a 3D figure using datacursor

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I am building a GUI that plot a 3D figure by pressing button. I am trying to return a distance value between 2 points when I select the 2 points using datacursormode on the figure. I know the formula to calculate the distance, but I don't know how to make the data cursor return the (X,Y,Z) value of the 2 points selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code, including what you've tried and what didn't work. This will help the community to provide you an answer.

Comment: function plot_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to plot (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

 % open my  save figure
plot=open('figure.fig');

 % off the axes line of the 3D figure
set(gca,'visible','off')

% activate cursor on the figure 
datacursormode (plot)
 
%handle of the figure
h= datacursormode(plot)

% my intend matlab function to calculate the distance between the 2 point.

%[x,y,z]= pdist([x,y,z],'euclidean') 

Thanks all

Comment: Next time you can just edit your original question, adding the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
%// retrieve the data cursor manager for the figure  
dcm = datacursormode(gcf) ;

%// get all the datatips information in a structure  
dtip_info = dcm.getCursorInfo ;

%// extract the coordinates of each data tip from the structure  
Coordinates_Datatip1 = dtip_info(1).Position ;  
Coordinates_Datatip2 = dtip_info(2).Position ;
```

---

This assume you already have 2 datatips in the current figure.
Each "Coordinates_Datatip" variable will contain 3 scalar values x,y and z position of your datatips.

Comment: @user3220520, when you post a comment there is a small help box which give you the correct syntax to post code. There is also a link for more help.