# how to easy select the pixel's position and pixel value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In order to classify remote sensing image by using k-means method in matlab, I want to select some samples in an image with an mouse clicking on it, but I don't know how to code that, could you tell me some method to accomplish it?

Comment: have you tried `Data Cursor` in the toolbar of the figure?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003365/matlab-gui-axes-extract-position-from-datacursor/28003681#28003681), you could re-use the base method. Or simply look at the function [`ginput`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`impoint`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoint.html), for example:

```
figure, imshow('pout.tif');
h = impoint(gca,[]);
position = wait(h);
```

this interactively place a point. Use `wait` to block the MATLAB command line. Double-click on the point to resume execution of the MATLAB command line.
`position` is specifying the coordinates of the point [X Y].